# Required and Placeholder clash on forms

Tags: forms, placeholder, required-field

I am writing a form and using the required tag and the placeholder tag on inputs. However inputs of type text do not seem to become required as the placeholder text is already making it validate.

Is this a known problem or is there a workaround? (example of form below)

Cheers

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
</form>
```

Comment: No, `placeholder` is definitely not supposed to interfere with the `value`. is it happening also on Browsers that support the `placeholder` attribute natively? are you using jQuery.Placeholder plugin?

Comment: You're missing a submit button